# Use polygons as clickable zones, instead of rectangles

Tags: c, allegro5

I'm creating a 2D game using the allegro library and I need to create polygonal territories on a map that the player can click on to move his units.

Am I forced to use some sort of point in polygon detection algorithm or is there a simpler solution using the polygon I drew already?

So far I managed to draw a polygon such as:

```
ALLEGRO_VERTEX v[] =
            {
                { .x = 0, .y = 0, .z = 0, .color = al_map_rgb_f(1, 0, 0) },
                { .x = 0, .y = 48, .z = 0, .color = al_map_rgb_f(1, 0, 0) },
                { .x = 32, .y = 64, .z = 0, .color = al_map_rgb_f(1, 0, 0) },
                { .x = 80, .y = 32, .z = 0, .color = al_map_rgb_f(1, 0, 0) },
                { .x = 112, .y = 0, .z = 0, .color = al_map_rgb_f(1, 0, 0) }
            };
al_draw_prim(v, NULL, NULL, 0, 5, ALLEGRO_PRIM_TRIANGLE_FAN);
```

EDIT: Ok I figured I can detect if the mouse is in a polygon using [this algorithm](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) still I feel this is not the right way to do this. I still need to call the function for every different polygon, that doesn't sound right.

Comment: Why that doesn't feel right? If you need to test if a point is inside a polygon then for sure you must iterate them all in a trivial approach. How would you know it otherwise?

Comment: You can use a picking buffer. Render twice, once with an ID color and once normally each on their own buffer. Then when you need to make a hit test get the pixel under the mouse and test it's color ID using whatever lookup suits you, hash map's are nice

Comment: @Jack you're probably right but as explained Joshua in his reply, I guess I shouldn't expect a built-in API and dive down into testing each polygon individually. It's just that it felt pretty complicated for an apparent easy task.
Also, not sure to understand the suggestion about the ID color. I've been trying to find code examples of such implementation that'd help me understand the canonical way of doing these things in games but was unlucky. Would you have an example by the side by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found an algorithm that does point-in-polygon for all your polygons and tells you which polygon the user clicked on. Good job you can use that. You wanted a built-in API call to do it and didn't get it. Since nobody else posted a contrary answer, I presume you won't. You should use what you've got.

I will now address why this should feel right rather than not feel right.

If the library itself had implemented it for you, it would still be constrained by the underlying OS primitives, which are in turn constrained by the algorithmic complexity of the problem, which *is* point-in-polygon per polygon. Thus, you may project all the polygons in your application, use one mouse hit box for the whole screen, and test them in turn. This is what the API would have had to do if there was an API for this.

I project a significant chance you coded it and found it too slow. An easy solution that almost always works is to do an axis-oriented bounding box test first, which is fast.

BugSquasher suggests an alternate solution. Render twice, with the second to an offscreen buffer with one color per polygon, and point-test the color. This also works, and is a good speedup if hit-testing is much more common than polygon moving. It does cost memory though.

Comment: thank you for taking the time of answering me. I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "an axis-oriented bounding box" could you explain a little bit more?
It's my first try of coding a game and having a hard time so far to wrap up my mind about the order of things!

Comment: @fassn: Draw a rectangle with horizontal and vertical lines around each polygon. If the point is outside the rectangle it is outside the polygon.

Comment: To make an AABB from a polygon, all you need is the min and max x and y values of the points in the polygon.